# jQuery filter with multiselect option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, crud

How can i filter with multiple select in jquery?

if i have table like this :

```js
$('#mask').on('change', function(){
  var isiwak = $('.wak').val();
  var isi = $("#mask").val();


  if(isiwak=="allwak" && isi == "all"){
    $(".allshow").show();
  } else {
    $("td:not(."+isi+")").parent().hide();
    $("."+isi).parent().show();
  }
});

//OnChange waktu 
$('.wak').on('change', function(){
  var isiwak = $('.wak').val();
  var isi = $("#mask").val();


  if(isiwak=="allwak" && isi == "all"){
    $(".allshow").show();
  } else {
    $("td:not(."+isiwak+")").parent().hide();
    $("."+isiwak).parent().show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th><th>Nama Maskapai</th><th>Jam Terbang</th><th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="b">b</td>
      <td class="pagi">02:09</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="a">a</td>
      <td class="pagi">01:08</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="b">b</td>
      <td class="siang">12:12</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="c">c</td>
      <td class="malam">19:20</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="b">b</td>
      <td class="pagi">09:12</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="c">c</td>
      <td class="pagi">10:20</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="c">c</td>
      <td class="siang">12:12</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="a">a</td>
      <td class="malam">19:20</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="a">a</td>
      <td class="siang">12:12</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="allshow">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="b">b</td>
      <td class="pagi">19:20</td>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a> <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a> <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<select id="mask">
  <option value="all"> -Pilih Maskapai- </option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<select class="wak">
  <option value="allwak"> -Pilih Waktu- </option>
  <option value="pagi">pagi</option>
  <option value="siang">siang</option>
  <option value="malam">malam</option>
</select>
```

I want to filter with two select, first select is for 'nama maskapai' and second select is 'jam terbang' where 'jam terbang' have class 'pagi', 'siang', 'malam'.

I want to use 2 select if i select 'nama maskapai' they will show all 'nama maskapai' and also with select.

this code just can filter with one select option.

Comment: Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/pma54tch/#&togetherjs=M43akkpCKV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make only one filter function, that would look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mask').on('change', function() {
    filter();
  });

  //OnChange waktu 
  $('.wak').on('change', function() {
    filter();
  });

  function filter() {
    var isiwak = $('.wak').val();
    var isi = $("#mask").val();

    var $all = $(".allshow");
    $all.hide()

    if (isiwak === "allwak" && isi === "all") {
      $all.show();
    } else if (isiwak === "allwak" && isi !== "all") {
      $all.children("." + isi).parent().show()
    } else if (isiwak !== "allwak" && isi === "all") {
      $all.children("." + isiwak).parent().show()
    } else {
      $all.children("." + isiwak).parent().children("." + isi).parent().show();
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Nama Maskapai</th>
      <th>Jam Terbang</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="b">b</td>
      <td class="pagi">02:09</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="a">a</td>
      <td class="pagi">01:08</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="b">b</td>
      <td class="siang">12:12</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="c">c</td>
      <td class="malam">19:20</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="b">b</td>
      <td class="pagi">09:12</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="c">c</td>
      <td class="pagi">10:20</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="c">c</td>
      <td class="siang">12:12</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="a">a</td>
      <td class="malam">19:20</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow" style="">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="a">a</td>
      <td class="siang">12:12</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allshow">
      <td class="num"></td>
      <td class="b">b</td>
      <td class="pagi">19:20</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRows(this)">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="naik">Up</a>
        <a href="#" class="turun">Down</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<select id="mask">
  <option value="all">-Pilih Maskapai-</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
<select class="wak">
  <option value="allwak">-Pilih Waktu-</option>
  <option value="pagi">pagi</option>
  <option value="siang">siang</option>
  <option value="malam">malam</option>
</select>
```

In the last else you filter for one select, then get the result and filter for the second.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3E5klznDsHzOfFceatiJ?p=preview) if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/u450y44d/#&togetherjs=jLBecdU8Pk):

JS:

```
$('#mask').on('change', function () {
            var isiwak = $('.wak :selected').val();
            var isi = $("#mask :selected").val();


            if (isiwak == "allwak" && isi == "all") {
                $(".allshow").show();
            } else {
                $("td:not(." + isi + ")").parent().hide();
                $("." + isi).parent().show();
            }
        });

        //OnChange waktu 
        $('.wak').on('change', function () {
            var isiwak = $('.wak :selected').val();
            var isi = $("#mask :selected").val();
            if (isiwak == "allwak" && isi == "all") {
                $(".allshow").show();
            } else {
                $('tr').each(function () {

                    if ($(this).find('.' + isiwak).length > 0 && $(this).find('.' + isi).length > 0) {
                            $(this).show();                        
                    }
                    else if ($(this).attr('class') == undefined) {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```